# Can I deploy Ubuntu Docker directly to EC2 (not inside Ubuntu)?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

All the solutions I know to deploy a Docker to EC2 involves running it inside a wrapping Ubuntu.
I want to deploy my Ubuntu docker to EC2 so it will be a standalone EC2 image running by itself.
Is that feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not launch EC2 with docker image, EC2 uses [AWS AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) to launch instance.

One to way to launch your docker image directly with [fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/), which does not manage any instance but will run your image as a standalone container.

> AWS Fargate is a compute engine for Amazon ECS that allows you to run
>   containers without having to manage servers or clusters. With AWS
>   Fargate, you no longer have to provision, configure, and scale
>   clusters of virtual machines to run containers. This removes the need
>   to choose server types, decide when to scale your clusters, or
>   optimize cluster packing. AWS Fargate removes the need for you to
>   interact with or think about servers or clusters.